# VS Code "Go To Definition" does not exist - Javascript

Tags: visual-studio-code, go-to-definition

I am using VScode version 1.57.

The issue is that it Simply cant not navigate to the definition, "Go To definition" not working.

as you can see in an image it does not exists.

What I have tried:

- clearing settings.json
- deleting all extentions
- resinstallign VS Code
- changing Key F12 to Shift + `

simply need to navigate to definition, I searched through documentation of VSCode it must read Javascrit files, I even added jsx and js next to ts, tsx but in this simple example below it still does not work.

[image: Visual Studio Code - go to definition not available]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, if I may ask?

Comment: @AlexGeorg reinstall OS :)

Answer (score 0):

Your import is importing the entire `./test.js` file as the variable `sum` thus there is no single method definition as you are expecting.

If you want sum to be your actual function called `sum` you need to change your `import` statement to:

```js
import { sum } from './test'
```

Comment: Thank you I made a silly mistake there,
unfortunately it does not fix the problem.